# EditText to TextView when button pushed

Tags: android, sdk

How can I make it so that it uses whatever is in the edittext, as the text view like if I type “hello” push the button and it sets the textview as “hello” then when you push the button again it erases it?

```
  package com.purelymean.earnings;
  import org.w3c.dom.Text;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Main extends Activity{
/**Called when activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Text et = (Text) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {





        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to **copy-paste** the text from EditText to TextView, or **cut-paste**?

Comment: you seem to be trying to use a "Text" object instead of an "EditText" object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it (adding on to La bla bla): For displaying the editText in TextView first create a method that happens when the button is clicked:

```
public void displayEditText(View view) { }
```

In your xml for your button add this:

```
android:onClick="displayEditText"
```

To get the EditText value put this inside the displayEditText

`String editTextValue =   et.getText().toString`;
To display this do the following:

```
tx.setText(editTextValue);
```

Final solution:

```
public void displayEditText(View view) {        
    if (tx.getText().toString().equals("")) {
         String editTextValue =   et.getText().toString;
           tx.setText(editTextValue);
    } else {
         tx.setText("");
         tv.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, however you're missing the part where another click is erasing the text. your solution will only erase it if the EditText is empty. if that's what he need, that's a good solution, if not, some sort of deletion need to be added.

Comment: I know. I did not want to copy your answer. You already showed how to erase the text view. I was just providing a better way for on click:).

Comment: oh, thought you forgot that. then it that case, great answer. up vote.
I always forget about this xml stuff..

Answer (score 1):

well, if you'd read about how to use it, you could have figured it out yourself, but any way:

```
package com.purelymean.earnings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


private boolean isErase = false;
private EditText et;
private TextView tx;

public class Main extends Activity{
/**Called when activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);


b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(isErase) {
            tx.setText(et.getText().toString());
        } else {
            tx.setText("");
        }
        isErase = !isErase;
    }
});

}
```

You simply get the text from the EditText, and set it as the TextView's text. than you change the state of the boolean variable, so it would erase next time it is clicked.

Also note, I change from Text object to EditText
The code is untested, might contains typos and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.purelymean.earnings;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity{
   // You have to save reference to views that will be used in onClick handler.
   EditText et;  
   TextView tx;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // If TextView is empty - copy string from EditText
        if (tx.getText().toString().equals("")) {
             tx.setText(et.getText().toString());
        } else { // Otherwise, clear the TextView.
             tx.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) pass your textview id  in this function

```
       private void EditToText(TextView tv) {

        tv.setCursorVisible(false);
        tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        tv.setEnabled(false);

    }
```